# Passing iterator as an argument

Tags: c++, templates, iterator

I am trying to write a template function that can accept any iterator as an argument.

For example, I should be able to pass arrays, lists, vectors of all types through this function.

I was thinking of writing a function as follows:

```
enter template<typename T1, T2>
int proof(T1<T2>::iterator& it, T1<T2>::iterator& itt){

return distance(it, itt);
}
```

Where T1 should be the container type and T2 should be the arithmetic type.

I would ideally want to pass an array and vector using this function.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use `std::distance` directly. If you want to write your own algorithm, then take inspiration from STL code.

Comment: this will have a nice solution once concepts are realized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a nice idea, but prone to failure — consider, for example, that `vector` has an `Allocator` template argument that is defaulted and that you seldom specify yourself, but which is always there. So already your simplest use-case is more complex than anticipated, and who knows what surprises other containers may hold?

Instead just take the iterator type directly. If the code within the function works with an iterator, then great. If not, then it won't compile (or your users violated a documented precondition). If it works with something you don't personally call an "iterator", well, does it matter? It works!

```
template <typename Iterator>
auto proof(const Iterator& it1, const Iterator& it2)
{
   return std::distance(it1, it2);
}
```

Of course I don't recommend writing a function like this unless it does something more substantial than delegate to `std::distance`; for one, your return type was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

To write a template that can accept any iterator, simply accept any type:

```
template<class It>
int proof(const It&, const It&)
```

On the other hand, your template does nothing but pass the arguments forward to `std::distance`, so it doesn't seem to really add any value. It might be better to simply use `std::distance` directly.